# Difference between multiple BinaryReader.Read() and BinaryReader.ReadBytes(int i)

Tags: c#, binary

I was searching for a BinaryReader.Skip function, while I came across this [feature request on msdn](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/361391/provide-binaryreader-skip-functionality).
He said you can provide your own BinaryReader.Skip() function, by using this.

Only looking at this code, I'm wondering why he chose this way to skip a certain amount of bytes:

```
    for (int i = 0, i < count; i++) {
        reader.ReadByte();
    }
```

Is there a difference between that and:

```
reader.ReadBytes(count);
```

Even if it's just a small optimalisation, I'd like to undestand. Because now it doesnt make sense to me why you would use the for loop.

```
public void Skip(this BinaryReader reader, int count) {
    if (reader.BaseStream.CanSeek) { 
        reader.BaseStream.Seek(count, SeekOffset.Current); 
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0, i < count; i++) {
            reader.ReadByte();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no difference.  **EDIT**: Assuming that the stream has enough byes

The `ReadByte` method simply forwards to the underlying Stream's `ReadByte` method.

The `ReadBytes` method calls the underlying stream's `Read` until it reads the required number of bytes.
It's defined like this:

```
public virtual byte[] ReadBytes(int count) {
    if (count < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedNonNegNum")); 
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<byte[]>() != null); 
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<byte[]>().Length <= Contract.OldValue(count));
    Contract.EndContractBlock(); 
    if (m_stream==null) __Error.FileNotOpen();

    byte[] result = new byte[count];

    int numRead = 0;
    do { 
        int n = m_stream.Read(result, numRead, count); 
        if (n == 0)
            break; 
        numRead += n;
        count -= n;
    } while (count > 0);

    if (numRead != result.Length) {
        // Trim array.  This should happen on EOF & possibly net streams. 
        byte[] copy = new byte[numRead]; 
        Buffer.InternalBlockCopy(result, 0, copy, 0, numRead);
        result = copy; 
    }

    return result;
}
```

For most streams, `ReadBytes` will probably be faster.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me though. Why would ReadBytes be faster?

Comment: @Timo, if the number of bytes is large enough, you'll get a block memory copy and fewer total method calls.  ReadByte is virtual, which can add a small amount of overhead.  It's not likely to be a huge difference either way.

Comment: @Dan, @Timo: It will issue fewer requests to the underlying stream.  When reading from disk, that can make a difference.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot! By the way where did you get that definition?

Comment: @SLaks, Most I/O-bound stream implementations have some internal buffering, so I wouldn't expect much impact from reading single bytes vs. medium-sized chunks.  I haven't profiled it, though, so I'm honestly not sure.

Answer (score 2):

[ReadByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbyte.aspx) will throw an EndOfStreamException if the end of the stream is reached, whereas [ReadBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes.aspx) will not.  It depends on whether you want Skip to throw if it cannot skip the requested number of bytes without reaching the end of the stream.

Answer (score 1):

ReadBytes is faster than multiple ReadByte calls.

Answer (score 0):

Its a very small optimization which will occasionally skip bytes (rather then reading them into ReadByte)  Think of it this way

```
if(vowel)
{
    println(vowel);
}
else
{
nextLetter();
}
```

If you can prevent that extra function call you save a little runtime